# Identify type of ajax data to be submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, csrf

I have a JQuery code that adds additional POST parameters on all ajax requests for csrf validation:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, opt) {
    if (opt.type == "POST") {
        csrf_token = get_cookie("x-csrf-cookie");
        opt.data.append('x-csrf-token', csrf_token);
    }
});
```

**Question:** I'd like to know how to identify the type of the data to be submitted. Currently I'm submitting a FormData object but I have new functions that submits text type so I need to differentiate whether the data is a FormData object or text.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by checking the `data` option, and see what was passed in

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, opt) {
  if (opt.type == "POST") {

    if (opt.data instanceof FormData) {

      // formData
      var csrf_token = get_cookie("x-csrf-cookie");
      opt.data.append('x-csrf-token', csrf_token);

    } else if (typeof opt.data === 'object') {

      // some other object

    } else if (typeof opt.data === 'string') {

      // string passed as data

    } else {

      // anything else

    }
  }
});
```

The last argument is as you've gathered all the options passed when calling `$.ajax`